# How to implement this instagram listview parallax effect?

Tags: listview, material-design, parallax

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LrUS.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwL4g.png)

I have seen this above features in instagram app
it is something like each listview item has its own header, and it is sticking at top until another header of listitem reaches it.
can any one please let me know what is the material design used for this, i searched for it but couldnt find any samples.

i have a requirement to implement this.